# Как продублировать ASCII изображение несколько раз в один ряд?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
peng =( \
      """
   _~_    
  (o o)   
 /  V  \  
/(  _  )\ 
  ^^ ^^

      """)

if n == 1:
    print(str(peng))
elif n == 2:
    print(peng*2)
elif n == 3:
    print(peng*3)
elif n == 4:
    print(peng * 4)
elif n == 5:
    print(peng*5)
elif n == 6:
    print(peng * 6)
elif n == 7:
    print(peng * 7)
elif n == 8:
    print(peng * 8)
elif n == 9:
    print(peng * 9)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы картинки выводились в одну строку, а не переносились? И да, я в курсе, что тоже самое можно написать лучше через `for_ in`.

Comment: В `peng` уберите скобки, оставив кавычки и: `peng = repr(peng)`, или `peng.replace('\n', '')`, или `''.join(peng.split())`

Answer (score 10):

Алгоритм такой: разбиваем "картинку" на отдельные строки, дублируем каждую строку необходимое количество раз, потом обратно собираем строки в целую картинку.

```
peng =(
     r"""
   _~_    
  (o o)   
 /  V  \  
/(  _  )\ 
  ^^ ^^   

      """)

def mul_image(img, n):
    return '\n'.join(line * n for line in img.splitlines())

print(mul_image(peng, 3))
```

Вывод:

```
   _~_       _~_       _~_    
  (o o)     (o o)     (o o)   
 /  V  \   /  V  \   /  V  \  
/(  _  )\ /(  _  )\ /(  _  )\ 
  ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^
```

Чтобы все вывелось красиво, все строки картинки (где есть печатные символы) должны быть одинаковой длины (т.е. пробелы в конце строк имеют значение). В картинке в вопросе нет дополнительных пробелов после "лапок", и если выводить через функцию выше, то получится вот что:

```
   _~_       _~_       _~_    
  (o o)     (o o)     (o o)   
 /  V  \   /  V  \   /  V  \  
/(  _  )\ /(  _  )\ /(  _  )\ 
  ^^ ^^  ^^ ^^  ^^ ^^
```

В принципе, функцию можно доработать так, чтобы все строки добивались пробелами до длины самой длинной из строк, тогда о конечных пробелах можно будет не заботиться:

```
def mul_image(img, n):
    lines = img.splitlines()
    max_len = max(len(line) for line in lines)
    return '\n'.join(line.ljust(max_len, ' ') * n for line in lines)
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями (RegEx):

```
In [24]: import re

In [25]: n = 5

In [26]: print(re.sub(r'([^\n]*)(\n)', ''.join([r'\1']*n) + r'\2', peng))
```

Результат:

```
   _~_       _~_       _~_       _~_       _~_
  (o o)     (o o)     (o o)     (o o)     (o o)
 /  V  \   /  V  \   /  V  \   /  V  \   /  V  \
/(  _  )\ /(  _  )\ /(  _  )\ /(  _  )\ /(  _  )\
  ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^
```