# Вывод чисел в одну строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сделал свой таймер который считывает время в секундах, а после выводит их в нормальном формате. Но мне захотелось детализировать его сделав вместо простых цифр и двоеточий символы (словарь с ними ниже). Но возникла ситуация, что они выводятся каждый в отдельную строку и тем самым во-первых не влазят в окно, во-вторых выглядят не красиво. Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести все цифры и символы в одну строку. Код:

```
from colorama import Fore, init

symbol_numbers = {
    "0": """
            ░█████╗░
            ██╔══██╗ 
            ██║░░██║ 
            ██║░░██║ 
            ╚█████╔╝ 
            ░╚════╝░""",
    "1": """ 
            ░░███╗░░
            ░████║░░ 
            ██╔██║░░ 
            ╚═╝██║░░ 
            ███████╗ 
            ╚══════╝ """,
    "2": """ 
            ██████╗░
            ╚════██╗ 
            ░░███╔═╝ 
            ██╔══╝░░ 
            ███████╗ 
            ╚══════╝ """,
    "3": """ 
            ██████╗░
            ╚════██╗ 
            ░█████╔╝ 
            ░╚═══██╗ 
            ██████╔╝ 
            ╚═════╝░ """,
    "4": """ 
            ░░██╗██╗
            ░██╔╝██║ 
            ██╔╝░██║ 
            ███████║ 
            ╚════██║ 
            ░░░░░╚═╝""",
    "5": """ 
            ███████╗
            ██╔════╝ 
            ██████╗░ 
            ╚════██╗ 
            ██████╔╝ 
            ╚═════╝░ """,
    "6": """ 
            ░█████╗░
            ██╔═══╝░ 
            ██████╗░ 
            ██╔══██╗ 
            ╚█████╔╝ 
            ░╚════╝░ """,
    "7": """ 
            ███████╗
            ╚════██║
            ░░░░██╔╝
            ░░░██╔╝░
            ░░██╔╝░░
            ░░╚═╝░░░""",
    "8": """ 
            ░█████╗░
            ██╔══██╗
            ╚█████╔╝
            ██╔══██╗
            ╚█████╔╝
            ░╚════╝░""",
    "9": """
            ░█████╗░
            ██╔══██╗
            ╚██████║
            ░╚═══██║
            ░█████╔╝
            ░╚════╝░""",
    ":": """
            ██╗
            ╚═╝
            ░░░
            ░░░
            ██╗
            ╚═╝"""
}

        while True:
            try:
                times = int(input("Enter the number of seconds for how many I need to set the timer: "))
                break
            except TypeError:
                pass

        hours = times // 3600
        minutes = (times - hours * 3600) // 60
        seconds = times - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)

        list_to_print = [Fore.YELLOW + symbol_numbers[i] for i in
                         f"{str(hours).rjust(2, '0')} : {str(minutes).rjust(2, '0')} : {str(seconds).rjust(2, '0')}"
                         if i != " "]
        print(" ".join(list_to_print))
```

Пример нужного вывода:

```
░░███╗░░██████╗░  ██╗  ██████╗░░░██╗██╗  ██╗  ███████╗░█████╗░
░████║░░╚════██╗  ╚═╝  ╚════██╗░██╔╝██║  ╚═╝  ██╔════╝██╔═══╝░
██╔██║░░░░███╔═╝  ░░░  ░█████╔╝██╔╝░██║  ░░░  ██████╗░██████╗░
╚═╝██║░░██╔══╝░░  ░░░  ░╚═══██╗███████║  ░░░  ╚════██╗██╔══██╗
███████╗███████╗  ██╗  ██████╔╝╚════██║  ██╗  ██████╔╝╚█████╔╝
╚══════╝╚══════╝  ╚═╝  ╚═════╝░░░░░░╚═╝  ╚═╝  ╚═════╝░░╚════╝░
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как продублировать ASCII изображение несколько раз в один ряд?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710628/1365)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно отдельно собрать отдельные строки выводимого текста из каждой отдельной строки каждой цифры, потом их вывести:

```
symbol_numbers = {
    "0": """
            ░█████╗░
            ██╔══██╗ 
            ██║░░██║ 
            ██║░░██║ 
            ╚█████╔╝ 
            ░╚════╝░""",
    ...,
    "9": """
            ░█████╗░
            ██╔══██╗
            ╚██████║
            ░╚═══██║
            ░█████╔╝
            ░╚════╝░""",
    ":": """
            ██╗
            ╚═╝
            ░░░
            ░░░
            ██╗
            ╚═╝"""
}


def show(text):
    lines = ['' for _ in range(7)]  # 7 - количество строк в каждом символе
    for c in text:
        symbol = symbol_numbers[c].split('\n')  # Разбить символ на отдельные строки
        # Добавить каждую строку символа к соответствующей строке результата
        for i, line in enumerate(symbol):
            lines[i] += line.strip() + ' '

    print(*lines, sep='\n')


show("12:34:56")
```

Вывод:

```
        
░░███╗░░ ██████╗░ ██╗ ██████╗░ ░░██╗██╗ ██╗ ███████╗ ░█████╗░ 
░████║░░ ╚════██╗ ╚═╝ ╚════██╗ ░██╔╝██║ ╚═╝ ██╔════╝ ██╔═══╝░
██╔██║░░ ░░███╔═╝ ░░░ ░█████╔╝ ██╔╝░██║ ░░░ ██████╗░ ██████╗░ 
╚═╝██║░░ ██╔══╝░░ ░░░ ░╚═══██╗ ███████║ ░░░ ╚════██╗ ██╔══██╗
███████╗ ███████╗ ██╗ ██████╔╝ ╚════██║ ██╗ ██████╔╝ ╚█████╔╝
╚══════╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═╝ ╚═════╝░ ░░░░░╚═╝ ╚═╝ ╚═════╝░ ░╚════╝░
```